# Cannot log in to mysql after default install with Macports

Tags: mysql, macports

I've installed mysql5 using Macports and the installation appears to check out but I cannot login to the server at all.

This is what I did:

> sudo port install mysql5-server

This builds and installs fine.

> sudo /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysql_install_db --user=mysql

This runs fine as well. It outputs the following:

> Installing MySQL system tables...
>   OK
>   Filling help tables...
>   OK
>
> To start mysqld at boot time you have to copy
>   support-files/mysql.server to the right place for your system
>
> PLEASE REMEMBER TO SET A PASSWORD FOR THE MySQL root USER !
>   To do so, start the server, then issue the following commands:
>
> /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'new-password'
>   /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysqladmin -u root -h LeoMacBook.local password 'new-password'
>
> Alternatively you can run:
>   /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysql_secure_installation
>
> which will also give you the option of removing the test
>   databases and anonymous user created by default.  This is
>   strongly recommended for production servers.
>
> See the manual for more instructions.
>
> You can start the MySQL daemon with:
>   cd /opt/local ; /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysqld_safe &
>
> You can test the MySQL daemon with mysql-test-run.pl
>   cd /opt/local/mysql-test ; perl mysql-test-run.pl
>
> Please report any problems with the /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysqlbug script!

Now...let's follow the instructions exactly. I start the server:

> sudo /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysqld_safe &

Server is running fine.

When I try to change the root password, I CANNOT log in.

> LeoMacBook:bin leonardteo$ /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'new-password'
>   /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
>   error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

I'm at wits end.

I've started the server with --skip-grant-tables. With this, I can load up mysql fine from the command line and I'm connected to the server. When I run SELECT * FROM mysql.user;, it returns an empty set! With this, I've tried to create a new user by invoking the command:

> CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';

But this doesn't work. I get the error:

> ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement

I cannot get this working. It seems I am so close, yet the root user seems to be missing.

Any ideas?

Leonard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you've started up mysql with --skip-grant-tables, issue a [`flush privileges;`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/flush.html) query. This'll re-enable the permissions system and allow you to run the usual `grant` and `create user` queries.

Comment: BINGO. Thanks Marc. Should have asked the question long before trying a dozen other things..... :)